# Does the IComparer interface work on a separate thread in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, sorting, thread-safety

I am using a generic ListView sorter implementing the `IComparer` interface.

Is this working on a separate thread from the main thread?

I have some funky results. It Sorts a static ListView just fine, however, once it gets populated with streaming data (it subscribes to some events that constantly add items to it) comparing fails and it becomes funky.

If its on a separate thread - any ideas on how should I modify it so it doesn't interfere with the populating results (or vice-versa)?

Or if it IS on the same threads, any ideas on why this is happening?

Below is the code for update method that updates the listView (`lstTrades`)

EDIT: I PASTED THE WRONG CODE ORIGINALLY!!

```
  private void UpdateList(foo t)
                {
                lstTrades.Items.Add(t.a);
                int i = lstTrades.Items.Count - 1;
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(t.b);
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(t.c.ToString());
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(t.d.ToString());
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Math.Round(e.pnl, 2).ToString());
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(t.f.ToString());
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(t.g.ToShortTimeString());
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(t.h);
                lstTrades.Items[i].SubItems.Add(t.i.ToString());
                }
```

The sort code is a gently modified code from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;


namespace Aladmin2
{


/// <summary>
/// This class is an implementation of the 'IComparer' interface.
/// </summary>
public class ListViewColumnSorter : IComparer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the column to be sorted
    /// </summary>
    private int ColumnToSort;
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the order in which to sort (i.e. 'Ascending').
    /// </summary>
    private SortOrder OrderOfSort;
    /// <summary>
    /// Case insensitive comparer object
    /// </summary>
    private CaseInsensitiveComparer ObjectCompare;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor.  Initializes various elements
    /// </summary>
    public ListViewColumnSorter()
    {
        // Initialize the column to '0'
        ColumnToSort = 0;

        // Initialize the sort order to 'none'
        OrderOfSort = SortOrder.None;

        // Initialize the CaseInsensitiveComparer object
        ObjectCompare = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is inherited from the IComparer interface.  It compares the two objects passed using a case insensitive comparison.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">First object to be compared</param>
    /// <param name="y">Second object to be compared</param>
    /// <returns>The result of the comparison. "0" if equal, negative if 'x' is less than 'y' and positive if 'x' is greater than 'y'</returns>
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int compareResult;
        ListViewItem listviewX, listviewY;

        // Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
        listviewX = (ListViewItem)x;
        listviewY = (ListViewItem)y;

        // Compare the two items
        DateTime dateValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, out  dateValue))
        {

            compareResult = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text), DateTime.Parse(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text));

        }
        else
        {

            compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
        }

        // Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
        if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            // Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
            return compareResult;
        }
        else if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            // Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
            return (-compareResult);
        }
        else
        {
            // Return '0' to indicate they are equal
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the number of the column to which to apply the sorting operation (Defaults to '0').
    /// </summary>
    public int SortColumn
    {
        set
        {
            ColumnToSort = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return ColumnToSort;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the order of sorting to apply (for example, 'Ascending' or 'Descending').
    /// </summary>
    public SortOrder Order
    {
        set
        {
            OrderOfSort = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return OrderOfSort;
        }
    }

}
```

}

EDIT:

I am only using 1 thread (that I know about/creating) in both updates and sorting

Comment: I don't think this is a threading issue at all- that's just a red herring (in this case).  You just are not re-sorting after adding new results.

Comment: Please note, I originally posted the wrong Update code, that one was the catchup code to generate the static list that works fine. Repasted new code

Comment: @Chris Shain - didn't intend for this to be a red herring. just scratching my head to see why this is happening

Comment: not a reflection on you at all.  It's an extremely common mistake with UI binding, and 3 people with a 200k+ total SO rep assumed that was the issue also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: In the article you mentioned, they have the line:

`this.listView1.Sort();`

Try adding this to your `ProcessUpdate` method, right at the end.

This sorter doesn't implement a continuous sort- you need to keep calling that as you add and remove data.  Sorry we all jumped on you about threading.

EDIT #2: Also, try this for your `ProcessUpdate` method:

```
private void UpdateList(foo t)
{
    // Create the item
    ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem(t.a);

    // Add all of the subitems
    li.SubItems.Add(t.b);
    li.SubItems.Add(t.c.ToString());
    li.SubItems.Add(t.d.ToString());
    li.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(e.pnl, 2).ToString());
    li.SubItems.Add(t.f.ToString());
    li.SubItems.Add(t.g.ToShortTimeString());
    li.SubItems.Add(t.h);
    li.SubItems.Add(t.i.ToString());

    // Add the item to the list
    lstTrades.Items.Add(li);

    // Sort the list
    lstTrades.Sort();
}
```

<del>If you are not already, you need to marshal the `ProcessUpdate` method (and anything else that touches a bound list) to the UI thread.  You can't safely update these from a background thread, for the same reasons that you can't touch UI controls from a background thread.

But no, the comparer is not running on it's own thread.</del>

Comment: tried it - same issue. What happens is that when I hit sort and new items come in - i get a whole bunch of blank sub-items. Looks like the subitems are the problem.

Comment: That's because of the way that you are getting the ListItem.  I'll edit my answer to reflect the right way to do this.

Comment: trying this now - makes sense

Comment: Yup! I looked ListItem is a web UI control, i am using winforms. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No this is not safe to use from multiple threads.  The `ListViewItem` instance itself is not unsable from multiple threads hence it's use within `IComparer` is also not safe.

Comment: well, I am using only 1 thread, but the question is that when I implement the `Icomparer` - does that make a new thread? Any suggestions on how to address this so that I can actually implement sorting?

Comment: @Sam no. The implementation of `IComparer` doesn't create a thread. No interface does this.

Answer (score 0):

No - it's not on a separate thread. An *interface* doesn't actually represent any executable code - only a contract between classes. So the question is how you are invoking the sort request and on what collection implementation. None of the built in collection classes (List<>, ArrayList, etc.) use a separate thread for sorting.

What might be on a separate thread however is your event notifications. If you're modifying the list on one thread and sorting it on another you'll get unexpected results.